# Print list elements by 1 column and 1 row, then 1 column and 2 row and so on till end of the list

Tags: python, list, nested

This is my list:

```
numbs = [[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [4, 5, 6]]
```

I want it to print like this:

```
1 2 4
2 3 5
3 4 6
```

I have tried using:

```
for xs in numbs:
    print(" ".join(map(str, xs)))
```

But it prints this instead:

```
1 2 3
2 3 4
4 5 6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are using python so you are looking for the built-in function zip():

```
zip(*numbs)
[(1, 2, 4), (2, 3, 5), (3, 4, 6)]
```

And formatted the way you asked for:

```
print("\n".join([ " ".join(map(str, l)) for l in zip(*numbs) ])) 
1 2 4
2 3 5
3 4 6
```